# Como controlar número de versão em orçamento?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, modelagem

Estou quebrando a cabeça aqui pra chegar num denominador comum, tenho um sistema em Delphi com PostgreSQL, esse sistema tem uma sessão de orçamentos

Eu preciso controlar as alterações feitas nesses orçamentos colocando número de versão, ou seja a cada mudança solicitada pelo cliente o vendedor reenviando um novo orçamento tem que registrar no sistema cada alteração.

Exemplo: Vendedor mandou 10 itens, cliente pediu pra deixar somente 9

Dessa forma o primeiro orçamento seria: 1.00, mas o segundo 1.01

Vou precisar controlar tudo, tudo mesmo, mesmo uma vírgula.

Estava pensando em clonar as tabelas (6 tabelas) que são usadas nesse orçamento e guardar os registros nelas sempre que houver um *update*, mas estou vendo que será bem trabalhoso manter esse espelhamento.

Pergunto aos colegas se já tiveram a necessidade de algo parecido e se podem contribuir com ideias, eu trabalho sozinho por isso recorri a vocês.

Comment: Pode colocar a estrutura das suas tabelas?

Comment: Você precisará voltar a "versão" do orçamento? Ou seria mais um Log?

Comment: Vou ter que deixar disponível pro vendedor poder visualizar o orçamento antigo e se preciso enviar para o cliente fazer o confronto, ou seja ele terá a opção de ver e imprimir o orçamento antigo, por isso estava pensando em clonar tudo.

Comment: David você citando um log me deu uma ideia aqui, posso fazer uma tabela como log de alterações e guardar os orçamentos enviados aos clientes em PDF numa pasta no servidor.

Comment: @Marcelo A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que clonar as tabelas não seja a melhor alternativa. O que você pode fazer é fazer com que sua tabela principal(qual eu imagino que seja `orcamento`) seja recursiva.

Para isso adicione um campo `id_orcamento_anterior`, assim você duplica os registros mas não as tabelas.

Quando você quiser pegar os orçamentos mais recentes você pode fazer algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM orcamento a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT b.id_orcamento FROM orcamento b
    WHERE a.`id_orcamento` = b.`id_orcamento_anterior`
);
```

Com o resultado dessa `query`, você também consegue pegar os orçamentos anteriores pelo campo criado.

Comment: Estou numa curva acentuada aqui, se eu usar a mesma tabela essa tabela vaia inchar até uma horas, pois toda alteração gera um novo orçamento

Comment: Então nesse caso, você seria obrigado de qualquer maneira duplicar as suas tabelas.

Comment: Pois é, esse é o detalhe... com uma tabela paralela a pesquisa de um orçamento mais antigo o usuário esta preparado se demorar um pouco mais, inchando a tabela principal deixaria o sistema lento como um todo

Comment: Se a sua tabela estiver bem indexada, acredito que não terá problemas com performance.

Comment: Roberto,eu uso Delphi XE com PostgreSQL9.x, não sei o que acontece, minha tabelas estão indexadas blz, um select no PGAdmin vai rapidinho, ja no delphi ele demora, pelo que vi é um problema quando uso campos MEMO, e eu tenho que usar esse tipo de campo pois na base muitos campos são tipo Text pois trabalho muito com textos longos, estou deixando pra estudar melhor esse problema depois pois a prioridade é versionar esses orçamentos

Answer (score 1):

É simples, considere cada versão como um orçamento diferente, tendo uma informação que identifique qual versão é. Você sabe que a última é que vale.Pode até ter algum mecanismo para congelar edições.

É claro que cada vez que for alterar parte do anterior para criar o novo.

É possível fazer algumas otimizações para ganhar espaço, mas aí já começa complicar um pouco.

Em, alguns casos a solução de ter uma tabela com os rascunhos e outra com o final pode ser útil, mas complica um pouco não sei se é vantajoso. teria que copiar para a tabela de rascunhos e remover a atual. Pode ser um pouco mais simples se considerar tudo rascunho e só quando congelar o orçamento é que copia para a tabela dos definitivos e aí não pode mais mexer nele. Não acho que compensa.